# What is a "shell:" in windows

Tags: windows, shell

Use "shell:sendto", I can open this folder

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

Use "shell:startup", I can open this folder

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

My question is, what is a "shell:" prefix? is that some sort of quick way to open some folders?  what else I can do with it? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3605239

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft official article says about "[Windows Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773177(v=vs.85).aspx)".

The Windows UI provides users with access to a wide variety of objects necessary for running applications and managing the operating system. The most numerous and familiar of these objects are the folders and files that reside on computer disk drives. There are also a number of virtual objects that allow the user to perform tasks such as sending files to remote printers or accessing the Recycle Bin. The Shell organizes these objects into a hierarchical namespace and provides users and applications with a consistent and efficient way to access and manage objects.